# How to convert access database and asp based website to wordpress or joomla

Tags: asp-classic

my client has an old website designed with asp but the site was not launched and sitting in a subfolder of the main site. The client wants to convert this site along with its database converted to wordpress. Is this possible? if yes, what is the easiest way to do it?

Please note that since the site was not launched there is no issue with SEO being lost.

Thanks

Comment: Is the existing site running off some kind of CMS? Does it have any functionality beyond displaying content (e.g. forms, searches etc)?

Answer (score 0):

This is far too complex of a task to "easily" convert. You must do a number of steps: 1) install wordpress; 2) find and install a wordpress theme that closely matches the current look of the site; 3) upload images for use in the theme to the theme folder and modify theme files as needed to exactly match the current site design. 4) create pages and/or posts to replicate the content of each page on the current site (uploading any required image/media files and installing any needed plug-ins to handle the page content properly). 5) test the site and fix any issues.

Those are the basics. Depending on the site and how complex the page designs are, it could get quite involved.